# Why does the pointer keep getting overwritten?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

```
void addPort(s **port, char *port_name){
    //s *pointer = malloc(sizeof(s));
    s * new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(s));
    if (port_name != new_node->name){
    new_node->name = port_name;
    new_node->next = *port;
    *port = new_node;
    }
    else {
        printf("Port %s exists ", port_name);
    }
}
```

So I have the above code which is meant to add an element to a linked list. At the moment all that happens when I add an element is that a new element is added and all the previous ones are changed to the value of the new element. For example: if I add Hong Kong and then print it will print 'Hong Kong' (as expected) but if I then add Rotterdam and print it will print 'Rotterdam, Rotterdam'. Can anyone see what my mistake is?

```
typedef struct port {
    char *name;
    struct port *next;
    struct port *ptr;
} s;
```

Here is the struct if it's needed.

Comment: `new_node->name` is uninitialized in your `if` statement. Undefined behavior.

Comment: Multi-dupe.  'new_node->name = port_name;' copies pointer only so that all nodes have the same pointer to the same, (probably out-of-scope), last string entered.

Comment: Probably passing the address of a static character array in main. Please post main code so we can verify  (The address will be the same for every element you add because it uses the same memory location for every string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void addPort(s **port, char *port_name){
    s * new_node;
    if (!strcmp(port_name, (*port)->name)){ // <-use strcmp() to compare string *contents*
        fprintf(stderr, "Port %s exists\n", port_name);
        return; // <-- return before allocating
        }
    new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
    new_node->name = strdup(port_name); // <- create a copy of the function argument
    new_node->next = *port;
    *port = new_node;
    }
}
```

---

Now:the same to check the entire linked list, not only the first node:

---

```
void addPort(s **port, char *port_name){
    s * new_node;
    for (; *port;port=&(*port)->next) { // walk the COMPLETE linked list.
        if (!strcmp(port_name, (*port)->name)){ // <- use strcmp() to compare string *contents*
                fprintf(stderr, "Port %s exists\n", port_name);
                return; // <-- return before allocating
                }
        }
    new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
    new_node->name = strdup(port_name); //<- create a copy of the function argument
    new_node->next = *port;
    *port = new_node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
*port = new_node
```

Above line is the culprit. It removes the reference to earlier node present in port pointer and makes it point to new node. In your case, initially `port` used to point to "Hong Kong" and the above line makes it point to "Rotterdam"

There are some other issues with the code too and it would not work. Please refer some linked list implementations in C online.